# How to update Height of the view Programmatically?

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, ios-autolayout

One issue i am facing related to autolayouts. I am setting height of view containing image views to zero first via autolayouts. But if certain function is called I want that height updated to a constant value, but height of my view is not getting updated. 
Here is the code, i have updated height programmatically inside the function but it is not working.

```
let heightContraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: businessImageView, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 40)
businessImageView.addConstraint(heightContraint)
```

Comment: Possible duplication of -  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43010173/how-to-programmatically-increase-the-height-of-uiview-with-swift

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to programmatically increase the height of UIView with Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43010173/how-to-programmatically-increase-the-height-of-uiview-with-swift)

Comment: [How to update the constant height constraint of a UIView programatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49776158/6822622)

Answer (score 3):

First create IBOutlet of the height constraint.

You just need to change `constant` property of the constraint.
For e.g.:

```
self.consTblFilterHeight.constant = 100.0
self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
```

Replace `self.view` with the parent view of the view you are changing the height.

Answer (score 1):

Create your constraint outlet and then set it like this :

- self.heightConstraintOutlet.constant = newHeightValue

Answer (score 0):

## Approach

- activate constraint
- change constant value

## Code

```
heightConstraint.isActive = true 
heightConstraint.constant = 20
```

Comment: Thanks that was a typo

Answer (score 0):

`businessImageView.addConstraint(heightContraint)` is not the code to update the constraint. It adds a constraint.
So as to update the height of parent view (which has images), you would need to update the constant for **businessImageView's** height constraint.

```
businessImageView.heightConstraint.constant = 40
self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
```

Answer (score 0):

// lets detect the height of our screen here

```
 int height = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height;
    int width = [UIS
```

creen mainScreen].bounds.size.width;

```
// share the news


 NSString *message = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"This screen is \n\n%i pixels high and\n%i pixels wide", height, width];
    NSLog(@"%@", message);
```